# Using node similarities in a graph or clustering viaualization

Tags: visualization, cytoscape.js

Use case:

1. nodes are documents
2. Links are links between documents that have an associated correlation (e.g., 0 to 1)

Being new, it is not clear how to apply those correlations or "weights' so that the document cluster in a logical manner.

Can anyone point me to an existing example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Positioning nodes is done by the layout.  Use any force-directed (physics) layout, like CoSE or Cola.  Those layouts allow your to specify how strongly nodes should be pulled towards one another on a per-edge basis.

Try some of the force-directed layouts to see which one gives results that you like.  Each one has different trade-offs (speed, aesthetics, etc.).

Just make sure to set the edge force for whatever layout, e.g. `edgeElasticity` for CoSE, to be proportional to `edge.data('weight')`.

Example: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/7b511e1f48ffd044ad66/